# Column and Null Space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking to get help with this practice problem. I need to construct a $3x3$ matrix whose column space contains:

\begin{pmatrix}
1\\  
1\\
5
\end{pmatrix} and  \begin{pmatrix}
0\\  
3\\
1
\end{pmatrix}

and whose null space contains:

\begin{pmatrix}
1\\  
1\\
2
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: The column space of A has those two (independent) vectors as columns plus one unknown column. For the nullspace Ax = 0 where x is your third vector. Over to you...

Answer (score 1):

As your first two vectors have to be in the column space, you can put them as columns of your matrix, so they will be included in the column space. For the third column in the matrix, as the kernel of a matrix is defined as all the space formed by the vectors x such that $Ax=0$, then you can generate the three next equations, being

$A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 &  0 & x_1 \\
1 &  3 & x_2 \\
5 &  1 & x_3 \end{array} \right)$, and $x=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1  \\
1  \\
2 \end{array} \right)$, so the three eqautions would be:

$1+2x_1=0$

$1+3+2x_2=0$

$5+1+2x_3=0$, and solving for them you get: $x_1=-\frac{1}{2}$, $x_2=-2$ and $x_3=-3$, obtaining your matrix. It is important to state that any multiple of this matrix $kA$, where $k\in\mathbb{R}$ will also be valid for your assumptions as multiplication by scalar does not change range and kernel spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The matrix $A$ has the two vectors of the column space as two columns, so it has the form:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&x\\
1&3&y\\
5&1&z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and it is such that:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&x\\
1&3&y\\
5&1&z
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So you have three equations form which you can find $x,y,z$.